# VBA Named columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet named "garcat_nv" with hundreds of columns. The first row contains the names that I'd like to give to each column. How can I loop through my sheet to give each column the name given in the first cell of that column ? This is an example of the Column AJ that I'd like to name GCFRRE.

```
Dim GCFRRE As Range

LastRow = garcat_nv.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set GCFRRE = Range("AJ2:AJ" & LastRow)
garcat_nv.Names.Add Name:="GCFRRE", RefersTo:=GCFREE
```

I attempted this loop:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range
LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To nbr_col Step 1
    Set rng = Range("i2:i" & LastRow)
    .Names.Add Name:=.Cells(1, i).Value, RefersTo:=rng
  Next i
```

I get a 1004 error. How can this be solved ? Thanks.

Comment: Check [Range.CreateNames method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.createnames). Based on a range of cells, it creates named ranges for each column/row based on top/first column/row. I think it's what you need

Answer (score 0):

The RefersTo parameter should be a string rather than a range - the string being the address of the range. Sample code might look something like this (but you might want to stick to your *lastRow* method rather than `UsedRange`):

```
Dim col As Range

For Each col In Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns
    With Sheet1.Names 'or ThisWorkbook.Names for global scope.
        'Remove any existing name.
        On Error Resume Next
        .Item(CStr(col.Cells(1))).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        'Add the new name.
        .Add _
            Name:=col.Cells(1).Value, _
            RefersToR1C1:="=" & col.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
    End With
Next
```